# horizontal scrolling list items images not fitting properly

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I am working on this responsive horizontal gallery, but now I have a dilemma.

I am trying to get 4 list items on a single shot (viewport).
The images are somehow not stretched to the full height.

Have a look and please tell me if my image size is not fine or something like that.
I need at least 4 images in a single shot.
Thanks
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SKEL2/)

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}
li img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

The code looks something like this. Please check the fiddle. thanks.

**Something like this** [**Link**](http://camilla.themevillage.net/#work)

Comment: That is not a jsfiddle.  http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: I would try and debug this but the fiddle is NSFW ;) at least where I work

Comment: ok let me create a fiddle for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SKEL2/

Comment: @zsaat14 here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/SKEL2/

Comment: Dont try re-inventing the wheel, this has already been done in a far more better way,http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SliderGallery/

Comment: Btw, where is the Jquery code ?

Comment: @dreamweiver  i am trying to learn from my mistakes. thanks.

Comment: @dreamweiver this is not what I am asking for.

Comment: If you want 4 images on each screen and you also want them 100% height, the images might be stretched, depending on the screens aspect ratio. amirite? I think this is a bad idea..

Comment: @JonasGrumann then how can achieve this?

Comment: What you really want .Can you post an image of what you have now and what output you want?

Comment: @Zword  something like this http://camilla.themevillage.net/#work

Comment: The images on that site are always 100% height and variable width that generates scroll ... [**LIKETHIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/SKEL2/2/)

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/SKEL2/8/ ?

Comment: @designerNProgrammer ok i understood.I will post a fiddle in 10 minutes

Comment: @JonasGrumann that quite correct. Please post a answer so i an give you some credit.please explain what you did here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/SKEL2/14/

I set all the widths to be 100% of the window (INCLUDING html and body), this might be a problem if you have other scrollable elements inside the page.

After that, I just positioned the images inside the

with position absolute, and gave them a height of 100% (this will stretch them to the bottom of the container, keeping the aspect ratio constant).

To keep it centered I used the

```css
top: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

The trick, that will keep an absolutely positioned element in the center of the container (as long as the container has position: relative)

I hardcoded a

```css
min-width: 420px;
```

to avoid the white borders around the images when the window became too small.

Hope this helps

Comment: also, note that you had an error in your css, you forgot a dot in front of "slides", you might want to correct that in your file:

    .slides {

Comment: there seems a little glitch here. why is vertical scrollbar showing? should i do overflow to hidden?

Comment: am not able to set overflow hidden to the body. Can you do that by css please and fiddle it re fiddle it. thanks a million

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SKEL2/15/

```css
* {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
slides {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  background-image:url('http://beautifulsoftwares.com/scroll/img/2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
li img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

`background-image:url('');` - Sets an image to the element

`background-size:cover;` - Property to cover the entire width and height with image

`background-position:50% 50%` - Centers the image

Comment: This is even better than mine, but it uses background images. I tried to avoid that as I thought that it's harder to work with background images when there's a server logic to load the gallery

Comment: @JonasGrumann This is realy good but I wanted your answer. basically i need the girl which is in center to be main focus. so thanks anyways.

Comment: @zword allright please tell me what does background size and background position has to do with it. thanks

Comment: @designerNProgrammer I updated my answer.Its your choice to select the answer which you find correct for your project. My fiddle i made according to the link that you provided

Comment: This is how I personally would do it

Comment: @Zword you anser was also correct that is why ive given you a helpgul flag. the point is i wanted inside lis and not background images, anyways thanks. KUDOS!

Comment: @designerNProgrammer dude its your choice . If you find the output of Jonas's fiddle correct then you should select that as the correct answer which you did. Thanks for the upvote btw

Comment: Though late but i really must say. Gr8 sportsmanship @JonasGrumann .I myself would never support or say any positives of another answer if i have answered to the same question.